# Looking for Image Slider that is based on default WP Media Library

Tags: plugins, images, media-library, block-editor

For my WordPress site, I want to have a new solution for my image sliders. What I expect in the frontend is a slider like I have here: https://my-road.de/la-digue-guide/

But I am not happy with my current situation because my images are divided into the default WP media library and the library of the NextGen plugin. Furthermore, the plugin requires too many resources.

In short: I need a plugin that allows me to select images from the WP media library and place it as a slideshow/carousel in an article. In the best case, this is possible within the Gutenberg editor. Has anyone an idea how I can solve it? Thanks in advance! I am searching for plugins for the last hours without success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Gutenberg Block Gallery plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/block-gallery/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try the block i built for this specific task, using the [slick library](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/)?

The Labels are set to german right now, but as you are a german blogger, that should work ;)

https://github.com/Impuls-Werbeagentur/impuls-slick-slider-block

Comment: I'll test your block as well! Thank you! :)

Comment: I have a few issues with your plugin. I just want to let you know how you can improve your solutions:

Comment: 1. I see a lot of alerts in Debug Mode (undefined variables)
2. On my testing site, the images are bigger than the content area, and pictures will not be resized. 
3. On initial page load, the slider has only a height of a few pixels when 'Slides überblenden' is disabled. 

I hope my feedback is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll look into it and update the repository!